# Unable to understand , how next address is getting computed in array , when performing operation &arr+1

Tags: c

I am trying to understand array behavior. Please see the code below. Size of int is 4.

```
int arr[]={10,9,8,7,6,5};

printf("\nSingle array print=> \n%u  ||  %u  ||  %u  ||  %u",
       singlearr, &singlearr, &singlearr + 1);
```

I am getting the output:

```
2293248  ||  2293248  ||  2293272
```

I understand the expressions "`singlarr`" and "`&singlearr`" but when I am doing "`&singlearr + 1`", why it is giving output as 2293272 which is 24 bytes after the address 2293248 (2293248+24) ?

Comment: Pointers cannot be printed with `%u`. You must convert them to `(void *)` and print them with `%p`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

&arr is a pointer to an entire array. So, if we move &arr by 1 position it will point the next block of **n** elements.
If the array base address is **b**, &arr+1 will be `b + (n * 4)`

here, n=6 and b = 2293248
so, `&arr+1 = b+(n*4) = 2293248 + (6*4) = 2293272`